# how to give grouping in input elements and insert into mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
<input type="text" id="reference_code" name="reference_code[]" required class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value("reference_code"); ?>"/>
```

How to use multidimentional to insert into MySQL using PHP?
Please check with my below code

```
Array
(
    [reference] => asdf
    [company_id] => 25
    [contact] => Sam Deva
    [sales_manager_demand] => 1
    [team_leader_demand] => 11
    [demand_date] => 11-05-2015
    [target_date] => 27-05-2015
    [state] => 11
    [city] => 328
    [description] => asdfasdfsadfdsf
    [countdown1] => 485
    [reference_code] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 300
        )
    [position] => Array
        (
            [0] => sales manager
            [1] => sales manager
        )

    [pri_skill_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 7
        )

    [other_primary_tech] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [sec_skill_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 5
        )

    [other_secondary_tech] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [minimum_experience] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 12
        )
```

How to insert these values into MySQL using a single foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$reference_code=$_POST['reference_code'];
$query="insert into tablename (reference,company_id,......,other_primary_tech) values "; //write insert with all the fields
$val="";
foreach($reference_code as $key=>$val){
$ref_code=$reference_code[$key];
$position=$_POST[position][$key];
$pri_skill_id=$_POST[pri_skill_id][$key];
$other_secondary_tech=$_POST[other_secondary_tech][$key];
$minimum_experience=$_POST[minimum_experience][$key];
$val.=" (".$_POST['reference'].",........,".$minimum_experience.")"; // values to insert
}

$query.=$val; //final query
```

You can try like this.....

Comment: Thanks It works. Another suggestion i would like to ask is have to generate unique id with these insertion 
    INSERT INTO `job_details` (`job_code`, `position`, `reference_code`) VALUES ('SIRAss554de5c2bb4df','sales manager','200'), ('SIRAss554de5c2bb4df','vice president','300')
above value you can see i have inserted but i need job code to be different

Comment: You can use time() or a combination of session_id and time()

Comment: how to insert multipel select array element example
[recruiter] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 7
            [2]=>23
        )
[0] and [1] value will be for 1st clone values and [2] will be second clone values to be inserted. how to insert please help me